# Change values in multiple columns of a dataframe using a lookup table

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns, lookup, lookup-tables

I am trying to change the value of a number of columns at once using a lookup table. They all use the same lookup table. I know how to do this for just one column -- I'd just use a `merge`, but am having trouble with multiple columns.

Below is an example dataframe and an example lookup table. My actual data is much larger (~10K columns with 8 rows).

`example <- data.frame(a = seq(1,5), b = seq(5,1), c=c(1,4,3,2,5))`

`lookup <- data.frame(number = seq(1,5), letter = LETTERS[seq(1,5)])`

Ideally, I would end up with a dataframe which looks like this:

`example_of_ideal_output <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[seq(1,5)], b = LETTERS[seq(5,1)], c=LETTERS[c(1,4,3,2,5)])`

Of course, in my actual data the dataframe is numbers, but the lookup table is a lot more complicated, so I can't just use a function like `LETTERS` to solve things.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that works on each column successively using `lapply()`:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(example,function(col) lookup$letter[match(col,lookup$number)]));
##   a b c
## 1 A E A
## 2 B D D
## 3 C C C
## 4 D B B
## 5 E A E
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind switching over to a matrix, you can achieve a "more vectorized" solution, as a matrix will allow you to call `match()` and index `lookup$letter` just once for the entire input:

```
matrix(lookup$letter[match(as.matrix(example),lookup$number)],nrow(example));
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "A"  "E"  "A"
## [2,] "B"  "D"  "D"
## [3,] "C"  "C"  "C"
## [4,] "D"  "B"  "B"
## [5,] "E"  "A"  "E"
```

(And of course you can coerce back to data.frame via `as.data.frame()` afterward, although you'll have to restore the column names as well if you want them, which can be done with `setNames(...,names(example))`. But if you really want to stick with a data.frame, my first solution is probably preferable.)

Comment: This is great, thank you -- especially appreciate the vectorized version

Answer (score 5):

Using `dplyr`

```
f <- function(x)setNames(lookup$letter, lookup$number)[x] 
library(dplyr)
example %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(f))
#  a b c
#1 A E A
#2 B D D
#3 C C C
#4 D B B
#5 E A E
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(example)[, lapply(.SD, f), ]
#   a b c
#1: A E A
#2: B D D
#3: C C C
#4: D B B
#5: E A E
```