# Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, read.csv

```
n = read.csv("Student_data (1).csv")
n = n[,-c(29:38)]
length(n)
nrow(n)
#BE
for (i in 1:length(n))
  {
   for(j in 1:nrow(n)) 
    {
     x=c("B.E","Bachelor of Engineering","BACHELOR OF ENGINEERING","B.E.")
     if( n[i][[j]] %in% x)
        n[i][[j]] = "BE"
     }
   }
```

I am tying to clean a data frame that has different factors of same kind but with different names and presentation say like Bachelors in Engineering and B.E. means the same thing which is "BE", so I am trying to convert all such  factors inside qualifications and specialization columns simultaneously using "for" loop as BE,similarly for others but it gives me an error as

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds In
>   addition: Warning message: In if (n[i][[j]] %in% x) n[i][[j]] = "BE" :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>    Can anyone help me out with this 
>   Also an better and efficient way than this is always welcomed!
>   I have also linked my .csv file in [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S45oAVRb0bbj0nm-cF_fxfyN2WKCv1cB/view)

Comment: your question is similar to this one. have a look at this once [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633302/change-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-using-a-lookup-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633302/change-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-using-a-lookup-table)

Comment: Please show your input and output data.frame. You can use `head()` or better `dput()` for that.